# JS Sorting an array of alphanumeric strings by ending numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Can someone please show me how to sort this

```js
var videos = ["https://example.net/download/7/video-104.mp4",
"https://example.net/download/7/video-105.mp4",
"https://example.net/download/7/video-106.mp4",
"https://example.net/download/7/video-108.mp4",
"https://example.net/download/7/video-110.mp4",
"https://example.net/download/7/video-112.mp4",
"https://example.net/download/7/video-114.mp4",
"https://example.net/download/8/video-107.mp4",
"https://example.net/download/8/video-109.mp4"]
```

into this

```js
var videos = ["https://example.net/download/7/video-104.mp4",
"https://example.net/download/7/video-105.mp4",
"https://example.net/download/7/video-106.mp4",
"https://example.net/download/8/video-107.mp4",
"https://example.net/download/7/video-108.mp4",
"https://example.net/download/8/video-109.mp4",
"https://example.net/download/7/video-110.mp4",
"https://example.net/download/7/video-112.mp4",
"https://example.net/download/7/video-114.mp4"]
```

it should be sorted based on last numbers in string before .mp4 but it doesn't work

```js
var videos = ["https://example.net/download/7/video-104.mp4",
  "https://example.net/download/7/video-105.mp4",
  "https://example.net/download/7/video-106.mp4",
  "https://example.net/download/7/video-108.mp4",
  "https://example.net/download/7/video-110.mp4",
  "https://example.net/download/7/video-112.mp4",
  "https://example.net/download/7/video-114.mp4",
  "https://example.net/download/8/video-107.mp4",
  "https://example.net/download/8/video-109.mp4"
]

videos.sort(function(a, b) {
  var spix = a.split('-')[1];
  a = parseInt(spix.split('.mp4')[0]);
  var spixb = b.split('-')[1];
  b = parseInt(spix.split('.mp4')[0]);
  return a - b;
});

console.log(videos);
```

Comment: In your comparison function, you can use a regexp to get the numbers at the end, then compare them.

Comment: @Barmar Added sample code. Doesn't work the way I need it to.

Comment: You have a typo. The second `spix.split('.mp4')[0]` should be `spixb.split('.mp4')[0]`

Comment: @Barmar Beating myself over the head right now...fml. can't believe how long i was stuck on something so simple. need to sleep more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with the defenition of variable `b`. You defined it incorrectly as `b = parseInt(spix.split('.mp4')[0]);` it should be `b = parseInt(spixb.split('.mp4')[0]);`

```js
var videos = ["https://example.net/download/7/video-104.mp4",
    "https://example.net/download/7/video-105.mp4",
    "https://example.net/download/7/video-106.mp4",
    "https://example.net/download/7/video-108.mp4",
    "https://example.net/download/7/video-110.mp4",
    "https://example.net/download/7/video-112.mp4",
    "https://example.net/download/7/video-114.mp4",
    "https://example.net/download/8/video-107.mp4",
    "https://example.net/download/8/video-109.mp4"];

videos.sort(function (a, b) {
    var spix = a.split('-')[1];
    a = parseInt(spix.split('.mp4')[0]);
    var spixb = b.split('-')[1];
    b = parseInt(spixb.split('.mp4')[0]);
    return a - b;
});

console.log(videos)
```

Comment: That's just a typo. Don't bother posting a full answer when you can just comment "You forgot the b".

Comment: Why bother using 2 new variables and using more memory instead of doing parseInt((a.split('-')[1]).split('.mp4')[0]); ?

Comment: @jasonmzx Maybe because it's easier to read when you split it into multiple statements?

Comment: @jasonmzx I have not added a solution of my own. I just fixed the issue with the code and made the code working.

Comment: Makes sense, I was just confused by that haha

Comment: This shorter version: `videos.sort(function(a, b) {const iv=s=>parseInt(s.split('-')[1]);return iv(a) - iv(b) });` would have worked also.

Answer (score 1):

```
videos.sort((a,b) => a.split('-')[1].slice(0,-4) - b.split('-')[1].slice(0,-4));

console.log( videos)
```

Basically I'm just splitting it by the "-" then taking out the '.mp4' and sorting it

Comment: I tested it on your data sample, it works